# How do I turn off highlighting of numbers in a TextView?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am displaying data from an RSS feed, including the date. The display is done in a TextView. When I display the date and time, the following numbers get highlighted in blue:

> 2011 15:27 -0400

I do nothing to prompt this highlight. I assume it is automatic highlighting, like with hyperlinks.

What can I do to turn it off?

Comment: please add layout file containing your textview.

Answer (score 1):

You could've set the `android:autoLink` attribute. This attribute should be set to:

```
android:autoLink="none"
```

Note that `none` is default value. So you can just omit `android:autoLink` altogether and `TextView` should not highlight anything in such case. For more details see [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3aautoLink).

Comment: Great. I'm going to use android:autoLink="web" since I want HTTP but not phone numbers linked. Thanks a ton.